# SQL - Finding largest period of activity by customer

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, aggregate, aggregation

I had a difficult time w/ the title, hope this is a little clearer...

I have a table of data (simplified) like so;

<kbd>Date</kbd>       
<kbd>Customer</kbd>
<kbd>Amount</kbd>

<kbd>1/1/2014</kbd>
<kbd>1</kbd>              
<kbd>100.5</kbd>   

<kbd>4/4/2014</kbd>
<kbd>1</kbd>              
<kbd>122.5</kbd>   

<kbd>2/1/2014</kbd>
<kbd>3</kbd>              
<kbd>3.25</kbd>

...but just short of a million records.

I would like to find the x day (let's say 90) period for each customer that has the largest total amount.

To phase the question a little differently, given all the transactions for all customers, for each customer I would like to find the 90 day period that has the largest total amount and what that total amount is in the period.

Trying to advise a brute force approach where I define all the possible ranges (or iterate over all possible ranges on the fly).

Any thoughts on a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a self-join for this, but the performance may not be so great:

```
select t.*,
       (select sum(t2.amount)
        from table t2
        where t2.customer = t.customer and
              t2.date >= dateadd(day, -90, t.date) and t2.date <= t.date
       ) as amount90
from table t;
```

There is a more efficient method in SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, what's the more efficient method in 2012, might just pull the data over to an 2012 instance.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a psuedo-code ish kind of answer that I think would work. It'd probably be really slow though.

You could have a function that calculates the number of activities provided a start date and number of days,

```
--function F
@userid, @startdate, @dayCount
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM TABLE 
WHERE 
UserID = @userid
and date > @startDate
and date < Dateadd(@startdate, @dayCount)
```

and then do a max on that function?

```
select max(f(user, date)) 
from TableContainingDateRanges
```